# Pass data between UIview inside ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, swift3, uiviewcontroller

I have a Viewcontroller, and it has a View outsite it (in between those 3 symbols (viewcontroller, first responder, exit)), and when I click on a button it shows up my View, then I created a class file for it, and the textfields data inside this View has to come back to the ViewController.
How do I do that? I only know the method by segues.
tks

Comment: [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate)

Comment: Sorry, I am new in swift, i would need an example. how can I go from this: override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == segueAddQuoteViewController {
        if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? AddQuoteViewController {
            // Configure View Controller
            destinationViewController.managedObjectContext = persistentContainer.viewContext
        }
    }
}    private let segueAddQuoteViewController = "SegueAddQuoteViewController"
........... to what I need?

Comment: @tiago.. -  Do not post code in comments. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44935196/edit) your question with all relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question, you're trying to reference the view objects inside your ViewController. For this, you don't need a separate class for the view. You have two options to reference views objects in ViewController:

1. Create objects in code, after the view is loaded in ViewController;
2. Connect the objects to @IBOulets in UI Editor.

The second option is more easy. Mainly if you are starting with Swift. You can learn to do this in this [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-ZaRC8L6uE). Or check this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24013373/how-do-you-use-interface-builder-with-swift).

Answer (score 0):

1. Tell your view controller it conforms to UITextFieldDelegate protocol.

   ```
   class MyViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
   ```
2. Ensure your UITextField delegate property is connected to the view controller.  You can do this through IB or through code.

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

   //... later on...

   myTextField.delegate = self
   ```
3. Implement any UITextFieldDelegate method from the reference in your view controller.  Example:

   ```
   func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
       print("text value is: \(textField.text)")
   }
   ```